# Pivoting 4x4 into 16x1

Tags: r, excel, pivot

I have been trying to find a way to pivot a dataset with 4 columns into one row. I will show an example of what I mean.

[image]

I want this dataset to be transformed into...

[image]

My problem comes when I try to use the pivot function in Excel, it doesn't allow me to pivot the data into one row. I've also tried many other functions in Excel but haven't had much luck.

Currently, the data is in Excel and would probably be easier to manipulate there. However, if Excel simply doesn't have that functionality then R would work just fine as well. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be solvable using Excel functions in the latest versions of Excel 365.

But it can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

I provide two different methods of doing this. You should test to see which is more efficient on your actual data

***M Code Version 1***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="myTable"]}[Content],
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(colNames, each {_, Int64.Type})),

x = List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(colNames,1),(cn)=>{cn, cn & Text.From(1)}),

//put each row in wide format
    tableData = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type", colNames{0}),
    wideList = List.Generate(
        ()=>[r= tableData{0}, idx=0],
        each [idx] < Table.RowCount(tableData),
        each [r=tableData{[idx]+1}, idx = [idx]+1],
        each   Record.RenameFields([r], List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(colNames,1), (cn)=>{cn, cn & "_" & Text.From([idx]+1)}))),
    wideTable = Table.FromRecords({Record.Combine(wideList)}),
    #"Wide Table Typed Columns" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(wideTable, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(wideTable), each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    #"Wide Table Typed Columns"
```

***M Code Version2***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="myTable"]}[Content],
    
//set data types
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(colNames, each {_, Int64.Type})),

//Unpivot to => three columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Group by ID
//then Pivot and rename the columns
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"ID"}, {
        {"pivot", each Table.ToRecords(Table.RemoveColumns( 
            Table.RenameColumns(
                Table.Pivot(_, List.Distinct([Attribute]), "Attribute","Value"),
                List.Transform(List.Distinct([Attribute]), (cn)=>{cn, cn & Number.ToText([ID]{0},"_0")})),
                    "ID"))}
        }),

    wide = Table.FromRecords({Record.Combine(List.Combine(#"Grouped Rows"[pivot]))}),

//set data types
    typedWide = Table.TransformColumnTypes(wide, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(wide), each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    typedWide
```

***Source Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A trick would be to reshaping data first into long format and then into wide format after few manipulations using tidyr from tidyverse family:
I first stored your example data in R called 'df':

```
  df
  ID sit1 sit2 sit3 sit4
  1   -1    2    0    0
  2   -3   -2   -3   -2
  3   -1    2    0    4
  4   -1    2    0    0
```

convert df into long format putting all sit columns into one
single column called 'sit':

```
dflong<-pivot_longer(df[,-c(1)],cols = everything(),names_to = 
                     'sit',values_to = 'values')
```

make the values of sit unique :

```
dflong$sit<-paste(dflong$sit,rep(c(1:4),each=4),sep = '_')
```

then reshape the data to wide format assigning each sit value into a column

```
dfwide<-pivot_wider(dflong,names_from = 'sit',values_from = 'values')
```

Hope that would be helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~sit1, ~sit2, ~sit3, ~sit4,
  1,   -1,    2,    0,    0,
  2,   -3,   -2,   -3,   -2,
  3,   -1,    2,    0,    4,
  4,   -1,    2,    0,    0 
)

library(tidyr)

col_order <- expand.grid(names(df)[-1], df$ID) |> 
  unite("Var", c(Var1, Var2))

df |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = starts_with("sit")) |> 
  dplyr::relocate(col_order$Var)

# A tibble: 1 × 16
  sit1_1 sit2_1 sit3_1 sit4_1 sit1_2 sit2_2 sit3_2 sit4_2 sit1_3 sit2_3 sit3_3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     -1      2      0      0     -3     -2     -3     -2     -1      2      0
# … with 5 more variables: sit4_3 <dbl>, sit1_4 <dbl>, sit2_4 <dbl>, sit3_4 <dbl>,
#   sit4_4 <dbl>
```

Comment: The OP asked for a rowwise expansion. (Column-wise expansion would have been trivial with unlist.)